# How do I make a program that rounds decimals to the amount that I want?

Tags: c#

I've created a basic calculator but now I want to add a textbox where the person can pick the amount of decimals that will be displayed on the answer box.

So for example if I wrote in 1/3 it would equal 0,33333333... and if I only wanted 3 decimals for example, I'd write in 3 in a textbox and clicka button and the answer would instead show 0,333.

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int antal= int.Parse(tbxDeci.Text); // tbxDeci is the textbox where they write how many decimals that will be used
        double svar = double.Parse(lblSvar.Text);  //  lblSvar is the label where the answer would display, in our case the 0,333...
        double deci = Math.Round(svar, antal);
        lblSvar.Text = deci.ToString();

    }
```

However when I use the program and type in a number I keep getting the error "system.formatexception 'input string was not in a correct format.'"

Help me please I'm really new to coding

EDIT: double svar = double.Parse(lblSvar.Text);
is where I get the error

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error, but your approach looks like you may be introducing error into your results.  Calculators, in general, always maintain register values to their maximum precision possible.  If the user wants to see a lower precision, only the display of the value is altered, not the actual value.

Comment: So there you were, stepping through your code in the debugger. Where did the error occur? What input were you providing to a method in that statement?

Comment: "1/3" is not a valid number.  Writing an expression parser is the kind of project you keep on the shelf for a while until you learn what is hard to do.

Comment: Check the edit for where I got the error

Answer (score 7):

There's a great deal wrong here but it is all fixable.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Rename your button to something meaningful. "Button1" tells you nothing.

```
    int antal= int.Parse(tbxDeci.Text); 
    // tbxDeci is the textbox where they write how many decimals that will be used
```

First, if you *ever* have to write a comment explaining what a name means then **you chose the wrong name**.  Both of these things should have better names so that you don't need to explain them.

Second, this code will crash if there is not an integer in that text box.

Third, consider what happens if someone puts in a valid integer like "-1".  Probably nothing good.  **Assume that your users will do dumb stuff**.  You have to write code that handles when users do something dumb.

Fix all these things:

```
   int decimalPlaces;
   bool success = int.TryParse(DecimalPlacesTextbox.Text, out decimalPlaces);
   if (!success || decimalPlaces < 0) {
      // Do something here!
      // what do you think the right thing to do is?
   } 
   else 
   {
     // decimalPlaces is a non-negative integer.
```

Continuing on.

```
double svar = double.Parse(lblSvar.Text);
```

Multiple problems here.

First, again, name things so that they make sense without a comment.

Second, you have to use `TryParse`.

Third, if you want arithmetic that is exactly accurate to some number of **decimal** places then use `decimal`, not `double`.  Double can only represent fractions that have a power of two on the bottom; decimal can represent fractions that have a power of ten on the bottom.

Can you take the rest from here?

Comment: Thanks alot Eric! I havn't learnt about decimal or tryParse so I don't really know what the things do, I've only had 2 classes so far but I will look into these things to improve my program! This might be simple to you but to me this still looks very advanced hehe. Again though thanks ALOT I will look at these things to improve my program :)

Comment: @JohnTran: You are welcome. This is a good first exercise. And today is a good day to make habits that will last you for the rest of your career. (1) Give things meaningful, descriptive names without abbrvs. (2) Learn to use a debugger to examine the state of your program as it runs and fails. (3) Assume that users will enter bad data; make your program handle those cases. (4) Make your program *testable*, and write test cases for it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int antal= Integer.Parse(tbxDeci.Text); // tbxDeci is the textbox where they write how many decimals that will be used
    double svar = Double.Parse(lblSvar.Text);  //  lblSvar is the label where the answer would display, in our case the 0,333...
    double deci = Math.Round(svar, antal);
    lblSvar.Text = deci.ToString();

}
```

Comment: where would I put this in the code? I'm really new to coding :X

Comment: @JohnTran See update: That or something similar will accomplish the formatting part you will want a loop to replace the string portion with the correct number of decimals.

Comment: I misread your error, take a look. I updated the names of the classes you were using. It should be uppercase names.

Comment: It might need Int.Parse() or Int32.Parse() instead of Integer.Parse().

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting the error in the following line:

```
double svar = double.Parse(lblSvar.Text);
```

And that is to be expected. `double.Parse()` converts (if a valid value is passed) a string to a double. In the above line, you're converting the value of `Text` property of the `lblSvar` label, and until you `set` that property, by default it's empty. So essentially what you're trying to do is the following:

```
double svar = double.Parse("");
```

And since an empty string cannot be converted to a double, you get the error.

To achieve your end goal, you don't really need to first `get` the value of the label. What you want to do is get the value you want to convert, and also get the decimal places to which you want to round it off, and then do the `Math.Round()` and output the result into the label. Something like:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int antal= int.Parse(tbxDeci.Text);
    double svar = double.Parse(txtSvar.Text);
    // Above, txtSvar is a TextBox to which the value you want to round off is entered.
    double deci = Math.Round(svar, antal);
    lblSvar.Text = deci.ToString();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the already displayed value in the label, round it off, and then re-display in the label, your original code should work as long as you have originally displayed a correct *double* value in your label text. So your problem is however you're setting the initial value of the label is setting some incorrect value.

But I believe, since this is a calculator, better approach is to actually keep your decimals to their maximum possible length, and *display* only upto any number of decimals you want.

Comment: I don't really understand this, wouldn't this mean that there are 2 textboxes?
what I'm trying to do is write a number in a textbox for example "'3" and it would show up in a label where there has previously been an answer for example "0.33333333" and it would then show up as "0.333"

you are correct about the 
double svar = Double.Parse(lblSvar.Text); 
giving me the error though

Comment: Alright, your problem is clearer now. In that case, the reason for your error is that somehow your label contains an _illegal_ double value. Either empty, or something other than numerics, or something similar.

Comment: Well there's your problem. Your lable value that's supposed to be double is `=0.3333333333`. Which means, whenever you're setting it, you're adding an equality operator (`=`) to the value, and obviously that cannot be converter. You should only set the actual value, or if you must have the `=` sign then extract only the number before converting.

Comment: OH THANK YOU, in the division code I had written lblSvar.Text = " = " + division.ToString(); which was obviously dumb :P

Comment: You're welcome. But, @JohnTran, please also read the above Eric Lippert's answer, which is very thorough and informative. Your code has numerous problems and he has given a bunch of useful tips and information. Good luck!